# Server side template is replaced with uploaded document

Tags: ruby, docusignapi

I'm am trying to create an envelope for embedded signing with two sever-side templates and a pdf document I generated all in one request.  One of the server-side templates has a DOB tab that will be filled in with the data specified in the request.

I've reviewed some other questions related to the docusign api and composite templates with documents [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054335/adding-documents-to-envelopes-using-composite-templates-in-docusign) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20152788/incorrectly-applied-server-templates-with-multiple-composite-templates)  I've used these examples to format my request.

Here is the request:  NOTE: I'm using the multipart-post gem [here](https://github.com/nicksieger/multipart-post) to create the request, so some of this request is pseudo HTTP with some multipart-post info.  I'm not sure how to get a fully formed HTTP request out in order to post it here.

```
POST http://localhost/restapi/v2/accounts/2/envelopes
X-DocuSign-Authentication: [omitted]

-------------RubyMultipartPost
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data;
name="post_body"
{
"compositeTemplates": [
    {
        "serverTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": 1,
                "templateId": "3093E017-2E18-4A30-A104-0201C601CE5F"
            }
        ],
        "inlineTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": 1,
                "recipients": {
                    "signers": [
                        {
                            "email": "jond@gmail.com",
                            "name": "Jon D. Doe",
                            "recipientId": "1",
                            "roleName": "Proposed Insured",
                            "clientUserId": "jond@gmail.com",
                            "tabs": {
                                "textTabs": [

                                ],
                                "checkboxTabs": [

                                ],
                                "fullNameTabs": [

                                ],
                                "dateTabs": [
                                    {
                                        "tabLabel": "DOB",
                                        "name": null,
                                        "value": "1-21-1974",
                                        "documentId": null,
                                        "selected": null
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "document": {
            "documentId": "1",
            "name": "test.pdf"
        }
    },
    {
        "serverTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": 2,
                "templateId": "63CA2E24-BBB8-499F-A884-021580DF54AF"
            }
        ],
        "inlineTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": 2,
                "recipients": {
                    "signers": [
                        {
                            "email": "jond@gmail.com",
                            "name": "Jon D. Doe",
                            "recipientId": "1",
                            "roleName": "Proposed Insured",
                            "clientUserId": "jond@gmail.com",
                            "tabs": {
                                "textTabs": [

                                ],
                                "checkboxTabs": [

                                ],
                                "fullNameTabs": [

                                ],
                                "dateTabs": [
                                    {
                                        "tabLabel": "DOB",
                                        "name": null,
                                        "value": "1-21-1974",
                                        "documentId": null,
                                        "selected": null
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
],
"status": "sent"
}
-------------RubyMultipartPost
Content-Disposition: file;filename="test.pdf";documentid=1;name="file1"
Content-Length: 34967
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

[pdf bytes omitted]
```

The resulting embedded view only has two documents in it.  The 1st is the test.pdf I uploaded in the request and the 2nd is the server-side template specified by templateId=63CA2E24-BBB8-499F-A884-021580DF54AF

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong .. according to the other questions I referenced above, this should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each **compositeTemplate** object can only supply files from a single source -- and if a **compositeTemplate** object specifies a **document**, then that's considered the document source for that **compositeTemplate** object.  In that case, any documents that happen to be part of a **serverTemplate** within the same **compositeTemplate** object will be ignored.  This seems to be what you're experiencing.

The request you posted only contains two **compositeTemplate** objects, so the resulting Envelope only contains documents from two document sources:

- The **document** that's specified in the first **compositeTemplate** object.
- The file(s) contained in the serverTemplate that's specified in the second **compositeTemplate** object.

If you want the Envelope to also contain the file(s) contained in serverTemplate `3093E017-2E18-4A30-A104-0201C601CE5F`, you'll need to add a third **compositeTemplate** object to the request that specifies `3093E017-2E18-4A30-A104-0201C601CE5F` as the server template, and uses the **inlineTemplate** info to provide necessary recipient and tab information (as you've done with the other **compositeTemplate** objects in the request you posted).  [See below for full request example.]

Finally, note that the value of the **sequence** properties within each **compositeTemplate** object specify the order in which the **serverTemplates** and **inlineTemplates** will be applied *within the scope of that specific compositeTemplate* -- it does nothing to influence the sequence of documents in the Envelope.  It's the order of the **compositeTemplate** objects in the request JSON/XML itself that determines sequence of documents in the resulting Envelope.

The following request will result in an Envelope that contains the following files (in this order):

1. Files from template `3093E017-2E18-4A30-A104-0201C601CE5F`
2. The document that's specified by the request (documentId=1)
3. Files from template `63CA2E24-BBB8-499F-A884-021580DF54AF`

**Request body (JSON part):**

```
{
    "compositeTemplates": [
        {
            "serverTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": 1,
                    "templateId": "3093E017-2E18-4A30-A104-0201C601CE5F"
                }
            ],
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": 2,
                    "recipients": {
                        "signers": [
                            {
                                "email": "jond@gmail.com",
                                "name": "Jon D. Doe",
                                "recipientId": "1",
                                "roleName": "Proposed Insured",
                                "clientUserId": "jond@gmail.com",
                                "tabs": {
                                    "dateTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "tabLabel": "DOB",
                                            "name": null,
                                            "value": "1-21-1974",
                                            "documentId": null,
                                            "selected": null
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "serverTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": 1,
                    "templateId": "3093E017-2E18-4A30-A104-0201C601CE5F"
                }
            ],
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": 2,
                    "recipients": {
                        "signers": [
                            {
                                "email": "jond@gmail.com",
                                "name": "Jon D. Doe",
                                "recipientId": "1",
                                "roleName": "Proposed Insured",
                                "clientUserId": "jond@gmail.com",
                                "tabs": {
                                    "dateTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "tabLabel": "DOB",
                                            "name": null,
                                            "value": "1-21-1974",
                                            "documentId": null,
                                            "selected": null
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "document": {
                "documentId": "1",
                "name": "test.pdf"
            }
        },
        {
            "serverTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": 1,
                    "templateId": "63CA2E24-BBB8-499F-A884-021580DF54AF"
                }
            ],
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": 2,
                    "recipients": {
                        "signers": [
                            {
                                "email": "jond@gmail.com",
                                "name": "Jon D. Doe",
                                "recipientId": "1",
                                "roleName": "Proposed Insured",
                                "clientUserId": "jond@gmail.com",
                                "tabs": {
                                    "dateTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "tabLabel": "DOB",
                                            "name": null,
                                            "value": "1-21-1974",
                                            "documentId": null,
                                            "selected": null
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status": "sent"
}
```

Comment: Is this a common usage of the API?  Perhaps it's obvious to experienced users of the API, but it seems odd to a newbie like myself to specify a duplicate serverTemplate[templateId] and then expect an existing document in the envelope to be replaced.