# Docusign REST composite templates and embedded signing creates duplicate recipients

Tags: docusignapi

I'm having a problem creating an envelope from a composite template and having it not duplicate the recipient.  Here is a sample of my call.

```
{
  "emailSubject": "Please complete the following forms",
  "status": "sent",
  "compositeTemplates": [
  {
     "serverTemplates": [
       {
         "sequence": "1",
         "templateId": "5ff1b987-dc38-49b1-b394-840f10ad08bb"
       }
     ],
     "inlineTemplates": [
     {
      "sequence": "2",
      "recipients": {
        "signers": [
          {
            "name": "Bob Sample",
            "email": "bob.sample@example.com",
            "roleName": "Client",
            "clientUserId": "bob.sample@example.com",
            "recipientId": "1"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
},
{
  "serverTemplates": [
    {
      "sequence": "1",
      "templateId": "02d947aa-6320-4a6b-b4b4-79c4c733d0d0"
    }
  ],
  "inlineTemplates": [
    {
      "sequence": "2",
      "recipients": {
        "signers": [
          {
            "name": "Bob Sample",
            "email": "bob.sample@example.com",
            "roleName": "Client",
            "clientUserId": "bob.sample@example.com",
            "recipientId": "1"
          }
         ]
        }
       }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

When I look at the envelope it has Bob Sample twice in the signing flow. How do I make this call so that only one Bob Sample is required to sign?

Comment: Note I am basing the JSON of this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24965892/server-side-template-is-replaced-with-uploaded-document

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your JSON though that's not confirmation by any means.  My initial reaction is that this might be related to how your templates are configured.  For starters, you definitely have defined the `Client` template role in each of your templates right?

Comment: Yes the recipient is configured as this in the template
Order=10, Role=Client, Email=Email, Name=Name, Action=Sign, Identify=Email,ID

Comment: What if you take out one of those two inline templates?

Comment: If I take one of them out it works fine. Then only one Bob Sample is required to sign.

Comment: Or do you mean take out the "inlineTemplates" and leave the "serverTemplates" for the second one? If I do that I get

    {
      "errorCode": "INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_FOR_RECIPIENT",
      "message": "The email address for the recipient is invalid. The recipient    Id follows."
    }