# Docusign API - Secure Fields not visible for second recipient using composite templates

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I'm continuing to work with the scenario described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056137/docusign-api-composite-templates-unable-to-access-tabs-from-server-templates) and thus far I **do** have the ability as the insured (first recipient) to edit all secure fields that were created when I initially created my server templates. What doesn't happen, however is the second recipient (producer-who is also a signer) does not have those fields that were designated as required visible. This only seems to happen when I send an API call for signature on composite templates. When working with a single template both parties have designated fields available to edit. I understand this may be a configuration issue but wanted to rule out the possibility of essential parameters in my call being omitted. I have gone into console account features and set secure fields visible to all recipients (see Molly's [comment in the forum).](http://community.docusign.com/t5/Sending-Options-and-Features/Why-are-my-contracts-showing-up-blank-to-my-signers-A-Quick-Tip/td-p/3649)

Here is my call XML. There may be some redundancy (e.g. type, routing order) but I'm working from various examples. Thanks in advance.

```
<envelopeDefinition xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">
<accountId>123456</accountId>
<status>sent</status>
<emailSubject>another test</emailSubject>
<emailBlurb>This comes from Me</emailBlurb>
<compositeTemplates>
    <compositeTemplate>
        <serverTemplates>
            <serverTemplate>
                <sequence>1</sequence>
                <templateId>894ed334-4183-4b68-857e-01fe4829f79e</templateId>
            </serverTemplate>
        </serverTemplates>
    <inlineTemplates>
        <inlineTemplate>
        <sequence>2</sequence>
            <recipients>
                <signers>
                    <signer>
                        <type>Signer</type>
                        <email>insured@email.com</email>
                        <name>test insured</name>
                        <RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder>
                        <recipientId>1</recipientId>
                        <roleName>Insured</roleName>
                    </signer>
                    <signer>
                        <email>producer@email.com</email>
                        <type>Signer</type>
                        <roleName>Producer</roleName>
                        <name>Test Agent</name>
                        <recipientId>2</recipientId>
                        <RoutingOrder>2</RoutingOrder>
                    </signer>
                </signers>
            </recipients>
        </inlineTemplate>
    </inlineTemplates>
</compositeTemplate>
</compositeTemplates>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unable to repro the issue you describe. I can successfully create an Envelope from a single template (using Composite Templates in my XML request), where a data field is required/editable for the first Recipient, and the same data field is editable for the second Recipient (but optional -- since the field is 'owned' by the first Recipient).  Here's my request XML:

```
<envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
   <accountId>ACCOUNT_ID</accountId>
   <status>sent</status>
   <compositeTemplates>
    <compositeTemplate>
        <serverTemplates>
            <serverTemplate>
                <sequence>1</sequence>
                <templateId>TEMPLATE_ID</templateId>
            </serverTemplate>
        </serverTemplates>
        <inlineTemplates>
            <inlineTemplate>
                <sequence>2</sequence>
                <recipients>
                  <signers>
                    <signer>
                     <email>johnsemail@outlook.com</email>
                     <name>John Doe</name>
                     <recipientId>1</recipientId>
                     <roleName>signer</roleName>
                     <routingOrder>1</routingOrder>
                    </signer>
                    <signer>
                     <email>janesemail@outlook.com</email>
                     <name>Jane Doe</name>
                     <recipientId>2</recipientId>
                     <roleName>signer2</roleName>
                     <routingOrder>2</routingOrder>
                    </signer>
                  </signers>
               </recipients>
            </inlineTemplate>
        </inlineTemplates>
    </compositeTemplate>
  </compositeTemplates>
</envelopeDefinition>
```

Here are a few suggestions for troubleshooting...

First, make a couple of changes to your request XML:

- Try using **routingOrder** (lower-case 'r') instead of **RoutingOrder** (upper-case 'r') in your XML.  In my (limited) testing just now, DocuSign seems to be ignoring the **RoutingOrder** element if it starts with an uppercase 'r'.
- Remove the **type** element from the XML request -- this isn't
  necessary because you're mapping each recipient to a Template
  role (which defines recipient type).

Also, if you want both recipients to be able to Edit a field, double-check the field properties in the Template via the DocuSign web console to confirm that the field has "**Allow All to Edit**" selected.

[image: field properties]

Finally, it wouldn't hurt to double-check the Account settings (Preferences >> Features) to confirm that the **Display Initial SecureField** property is selected.  (Occasionally I've seen it where someone enables a setting, but forgets to Save the change (by clicking the SAVE button that's located at the very bottom of the page.))

[image: account setting]

Comment: Wow. Not sure if it was the routing order (given that it was set up for each signer in the template config), but the sig element on each template is now visible along with the required fields (the data field tag properties setting I'm certain helped). I did already have the display initial securefield property enabled prior to this test. Thanks for your help again!